# Calling a function or variable in the modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating a wizard in a modal and I am trying to pass and change a variable from a controller that I am calling in the modal:

ex:

```
function openWizardModal() {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                backdrop: true,
                templateUrl: 'template/user/wizard',
                size: 'lg',
                controller: 'WizardController',
                controllerAs: 'wizardCtrl',

            });
        }
```

In my WizardController there is a variable called "step", and I'm trying to change the step number for when I open the modal this show the next step, but I can't change it in the modal instance, is it possible what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your problem is: how can I share variable between two controllers? If so, solution would be to use additional service object for keeping your Wizard progress, then you could easily inject `WizardService` into both, modal and base controller and change its state (for example current step number).

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve variables into the modal controller:

```
controller: 'WizardController',
controllerAs: 'wizardCtrl',
resolve: {
    step: $scope.currentStep
}
```

Then in the controller you could just add a dependency called step and you'll have access to the variable